# Open a pdf file on a network drive with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Hi I am trying to create a script that opens a variety of internet pages and programs through a vbscript, but I am having difficulty opening pdf files that are located on a network drive, ive tried a bunch of commands but cannot get the files to open at all so any help would be appreciated :)

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
IE.Navigate "https://websiteaddress.com
IE.Visible = True 
Wscript.Sleep 3000 
WshShell.SendKeys "text"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "text"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "text"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "%{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
Wscript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "%{TAB}"
IE.Navigate "https://websiteaddress.com"
IE.Visible = True 
Wscript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.SendKeys "text"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.Run "H:\Shortcuts /k dir *.*"
WshShell.Run "Notepad.exe"
Wscript.Sleep 3000
WshShell.Run "calc.exe"
```

I am very new to vbscripting but I have tried the following two lines and neither work;

```
WshShell.Run "G:\pathtofile\thepdf.pdf"

WshShell.Run "NET USE G: \\server\share\thepdf.pdf"
```

Comment: please publish your script together with one of the attempts you made

Comment: Edited my original question with code and attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It surprises me you are new to vbscript and yet choose that language to do such things, vbscript is not very suited for this kind of work and the days of vbscript are counted, ruby would be a better choice if you want to use a program language and if you just want to automate things you would beter use http://www.autohotkey.com/

Anyway, like this it should work in vbscript. The "" represents a single " within a string.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """g:\path with spaces\thepdf.pdf"""
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply peter, the reason behind using vbscript is im automating my startup process at work and we are very restricted in beign able to download/install apps...I will of course look into the autohotkey app and also give this a try.